# Is it meaningful to verifyText() on an element that has just had type() executed on it?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm curious about whether the following functional test is possible. I'm working with PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase with Selenium-RC here, but the principle (I think) should apply everywhere.

Suppose I execute the following command on a particular div:

```
function testInput() {
    $locator = $this->get_magic_locator(); // for the sake of abstraction
    $this->type( $locator, "Beatles" ); // Selenium API call
    $this->verifyText( $locator, "Beatles" ); // Selenium API call
}
```

Conceptually, I feel that this test should work. I'm entering data into a particular field, and I simply want to verify that the text now exists *as entered*.

However, the results of my test (the `verifyText` assertion fails) suggest that the content of the `$locator` element are empty, even after input.

```
There was 1 failure:

1) test::testInput
Failed asserting that <string:> matches PCRE pattern "/Beatles/".`
```

Has anyone else tried anything like this? Should it work? Am I making a simple mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `verifyValue(locator,texttoverify)` rather than `verifyText(locator,value)` for validating the textbox values

Comment: ... and that's because `verifyText` looks at the text content of an element (*e.g.*, `<A ...>this is some text</A>`), and an INPUT element doesn't have any content.  `verifyValue` looks at the VALUE attribute of the element, and that's where INPUT elements have their "content" (*e.g.*, `<INPUT ... VALUE="this is some text"/>`)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your initial question ("Is it meaningful ..."), well, maybe.  What you're testing at that point is the browser's ability to respond to keystrokes, which would be sort of lame.  Unless you've got some JavaScript code wired to some of the field's properties, in which case it might be sort of important.

> Standard programmer's answer - "It depends".